# Warning triangle in ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center

I am using ubuntu 14.04. While installing certain softies, my ubuntu software center shows a warning triangle. Here is an example:

[image: ubuntu software center image]

So, there it is like this

[image: warning triangle image]

What does this mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it means "dependencies are not satisfied".

Just try to install one and see what happens I wont break you system, I could not find one in my software centre.